# Eclipse project unable to run/show errors although it has no errors in codes

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to run my android project. I've checked the files individually but it shows no error in any file. But still unable to run and it shows `Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application`

I've checked online and rebuild the project/ clean the project but it still shows me the error.

Here is the error log.

```
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.version=1.7.0_04
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_SG
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64
Error
Sun Aug 05 23:01:23 SGT 2012
JavaBuilder handling ImageBuilderInternalException while building: NFCTest
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: A resource exists with a
different case: '/NFCTest/bin/classes/com/example/NFCTest'.
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.checkDoesNotExist(Resource.java:308)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.checkDoesNotExist(Resource.java:286)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Folder.assertCreateRequirements(Folder.java:30)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Folder.create(Folder.java:95)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.createFolder(AbstractImageBuilder.java:469)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder$1.visit(AbstractImageBuilder.java:253)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource$1.visitElement(Resource.java:65)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:82)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:86)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:86)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:86)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.iterate(ElementTreeIterator.java:127)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:75)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.addAllSourceFiles(AbstractImageBuilder.java:218)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.build(BatchImageBuilder.java:51)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.buildAll(JavaBuilder.java:254)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:178)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:292)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:351)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:374)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: What of the error message "A resource exists with a
different case: '/NFCTest/bin/classes/com/example/NFCTest'".  Looked into that, yet?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing **64-bit** and **32-bit**. Download the 64-bit version of Eclipse and use the 64-bit version of Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have the same package in different(in this case src) folder.